# Android java.util.concurrent.Executors newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor example

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, executors

I am having a problem with Android java.util.concurrent.Executors.

I am trying to use newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor to run my runnable every x seconds.
I saw `executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, 0, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`
however it doesn't exists in Android.

The Android documentation [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) , does not give a clue how I should use the newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor;

Could someone give me an example how I should use it to run a runnable every x seconds? I know you can use Handler, but I am wondering how you can use SingleThreadScheduledExecutor to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an example here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util.concurrent/ExecutorsnewSingleThreadScheduledExecutor.htm

Actually [Executors comes with Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) .

Comment: Thanks! I was actually reading it before I made the post. However, I used a wrong type to start with.